# Substituir campo input text por button mantendo funcionalidade de filtro em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Encontrei este filtro em javascript que está funcionando e muito bem, mas ele é um input tipo texto, e gostaria de converter o input em links hrefs, mas não consegui ainda

> Como é:

```js
$(function(){ 

  $("#filtro").keyup(function(){
    var texto = $(this).val();
    
    $(".bloco").each(function(){
      var resultado = $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(' '+texto.toUpperCase());
      
      if(resultado < 0) {
        $(this).fadeOut();
      }else {
        $(this).fadeIn();
      }
    }); 

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="busca">
   <input id="filtro" type="text" placeholder="Busca Rápida">
</div>

<div class="blocos">
  <div class="bloco">
    <h3>bloco 1</h3>
    <p>Um texto para o bloco de numero 1</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bloco">
    <h3>bloco 2</h3>
    <p>Um texto para o bloco de numero 2</p>
  </div>
```

> Eu gostaria que ao invés do usuário digitar ele clicasse em um href  e fosse feito o filtro

```js
$(function(){ 

  $("#filtro").keyup(function(){
    var texto = $(this).val();
    
    $(".bloco").each(function(){
      var resultado = $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(' '+texto.toUpperCase());
      
      if(resultado < 0) {
        $(this).fadeOut();
      }else {
        $(this).fadeIn();
      }
    }); 

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div >
             <a href="#" class="busca" id="filtro" value="bloco 1">bloco 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="busca" id="filtro" value="bloco 2">bloco 2</a>
                <a href="#" class="busca" id="filtro" value="todos">todos</a>

   </div>             
   
<div class="blocos">
  <div class="bloco">
    <h3>bloco 1</h3>
    <p>Um texto para o bloco de numero 1</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bloco">
    <h3>bloco 2</h3>
    <p>Um texto para o bloco de numero 2</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Olá, miguel. Sua pergunta não está muito clara. Talvez seria legal se você clica-se em "editar" e adicionar mais esclarecimentos. O que você quer fazer afinal de contas? Já tem algum código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, segue o código, apenas troquei de keyup para click, o $(this).val() para $(this).attr("value"), o #filtro no evento do jquery, para a classe .busca (pois ele não pega mais de um item com o mesmo id), também troquei o valor do "todos" no html para "", desta forma ele busca tudo, e não um bloco com o valor "todos" testado e funcionando! Abrass!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div >
                <a href="#" class="busca" id="filtro" value="bloco 1">bloco 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="busca" id="filtro" value="bloco 2">bloco 2</a>
                <a href="#" class="busca" id="filtro" value="">todos</a>

   </div>             

<div class="blocos">
  <div class="bloco">
    <h3>bloco 1</h3>
    <p>Um texto para o bloco de numero 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="bloco">
    <h3>bloco 2</h3>
    <p>Um texto para o bloco de numero 2</p>
  </div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function(){ 
  $(".busca").click(function(){
    var texto = $(this).attr("value");

    $(".bloco").each(function(){
      var resultado = $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(' '+texto.toUpperCase());

      if(resultado < 0) {
        $(this).fadeOut();
      }else {
        $(this).fadeIn();
      }
    }); 

  });

});
```

Comment: Como fazer para que ao invés de mostrar todos, o padrão seja mostrar a tela sem dados e apenas mostrar depois que forem sendo clicados nos filtros é possível?

Comment: adicionei as primeiras 3 linhas, troque seu script por este:
`$(".bloco").each(function(index,bloco){
 $(bloco).fadeOut();
})
$(function(){ 
  $(".busca").click(function(){
    var texto = $(this).attr("value");

    $(".bloco").each(function(){
      var resultado = $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(' '+texto.toUpperCase());

      if(resultado < 0) {
        $(this).fadeOut();
      }else {
        $(this).fadeIn();
      }
    }); 

  });

});`